# Кастомный текст sfml

Tags: c++, текст, sfml

Я пытаюсь создать кастомный текст на основе sfml, но не могу получить ориджин для буквы из-за чего они устанавливаются криво.

Вот пример кода:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::Sprite sprite, sprite1;

    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("segoeui.ttf");
    sf::Glyph glyph0 = font.getGlyph('a', 20, false);
    sf::Glyph glyph1 = font.getGlyph('F', 20, false);

    sprite.setTexture(font.getTexture(20));
    sprite.setTextureRect(glyph0.textureRect);
    sprite.setPosition(0, 20);

    sprite1.setTexture(font.getTexture(20));
    sprite1.setTextureRect(glyph1.textureRect);
    sprite1.setPosition(glyph1.advance, 20);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.draw(sprite1);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У класса `sf::Glyph` есть поле `bounds` типа `sf::FloatRect`. Этот объект содержит такие параметры: высота, ширина и координаты крайней левой точки объекта (не забываем, что это прямоугольник). Поэтому можно выставить буквы в одну строку относительно нижней границы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого нужно получить высоту символа, а после отнимать  от нижней границы строки. В вашем коде это будет выглядеть так:

```
float height = glyph0.bounds.height;
float height1 = glyph1.bounds.height;
<код>
sprite.setPosition(0, 20 - height);
<код>
sprite1.setPosition(glyph1.advance, 20 - height1);
```

И вот тут уже сразу же появляется решение проблемы: можно знать высоту необходимой строки, что даст и нижнюю её границу - просто добавив высоту к *y компоненте* позиции, а это и есть `origin` для букв. То есть, чтобы сделать другой `origin`, достаточно добавлять(отнимать) вектор смещения для строки.

И как было сказано выше поле `bounds` содержит ширину буквы, что также можно использовать для горизонтального смещения букв в строке.